# Angular Universal - google is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have a directive that makes a text input into a google's places autocomplete input which looks like:

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit , Output, EventEmitter, NgZone, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'
// import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core'
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@laurentgoudet/agm-core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[locationAutocomplete]'
})
export class LocationAutocompleteDirective implements AfterViewInit  {

    @Output() locationChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private mapsLoader: MapsAPILoader,
        private ngZone: NgZone,
        private searchElementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.mapsLoader.load().then(() => {
            let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
                //types: ["address"]
            });
            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    // Get the place result
                    let place: any = autocomplete.getPlace();

                    // Verify result
                    if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    place.originalAddress = this.searchElementRef.nativeElement.value
                    this.locationChange.emit(place);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The issue starts when I try to serve the app using Universal. I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: google is not defined

Is there a way to resolve it? 
The easiest way is to put it under `platformIsBrowser` but I need it to work when the page loads.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @matan-kadosh Did you solve this?

Comment: Did you guys ever find a solution to this?

Comment: So this is actually pretty old. I don't fully recall how we solved that, but if I remember correctly we've ended up putting it under `isPlatformBrowser`

Answer (score 0):

- You should follow all the steps [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps).
- If you continue to face the same issue, you would have to create *.spec.ts* file so that google would be defined and surpass the error.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33454610)